# DataFrame.resample does not include last row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i wanted to downsampling my data using ffill method

I have a data:

```
2020-01-01  1.248310e+06
2021-01-01  1.259511e+06
2022-01-01  1.276312e+06
2023-01-01  1.298714e+06
```

The output should be:

```
2020-01-01  1.248310e+06
2020-02-01  1.248310e+06
2020-03-01  1.248310e+06
....        ...
2023-10-01  1.298714e+06
2023-11-01  1.298714e+06
2023-12-01  1.298714e+06
```

Here is what I tried

```
 down_sampling = df.resample('MS', fill_method= 'ffill')
```

I get something like:

```
2020-01-01  1.248310e+06
2020-02-01  1.248310e+06
2020-03-01  1.248310e+06
....        ...
2022-11-01  1.276312e+06
2022-12-01  1.276312e+06
2023-01-01  1.298714e+06
```

The problem here is the year 2023 has only one month.

Can you suggest any idea on how to fixed it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=4, freq='YS')
series = pd.Series([1.248310e+06, 1.259511e+06, 1.276312e+06, 1.298714e+06], index=index)
series2 = pd.Series(1.298714e+06, pd.date_range('12/1/2023', periods=1))
series = series.append(series2)
down_sampling = series.resample('MS').ffill()
```

Comment: thank you,but i think it's does not work well when i want to convert data from month to daily.

Comment: The same bit of code can't do everything without you changing it. If you want the last day to be the last day of the year, then you need to change the `series2` line to `series2 = pd.Series(1.298714e+06, pd.date_range('12/31/2023', periods=1))` and then do `down_sampling = series.resample('D').ffill()`

Comment: I think this is the best way,Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky but pythonic solution:

```
df.append(df.iloc[[-1]].set_index(df.iloc[[-1]].index.shift(1, freq="D"))).resample("H").ffill()[:-1]
```

It picks the last row (as a df: `df.iloc[[-1]]`),

increases its index by one step (here 1 day: `.index.shift(1, freq="D")`),

then resamples: `.resample("H").ffill()`

And removes the single dummy row at the end of df (`[:-1]`)

I'd actually expect `closed:` parameter of `resample` to do the job.